# Did Prophet Muhammad(S.A.W) said the sun make sujud

Tags: quran, hadith, islamic-philosophy, islamic-scholar

Asalam aleykum Warahma tul Lahi wabarakatu.peace be upon our prophet Muhammad S.A.w, a week ago i was having a conversation with my friend who is educated in islam.On our conversation he mention there was a day prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) Peace be upon him `"he was talking with swahabas and he ask them do you know when the sun set where does it go, swahabas says ya rasulllah we don't know then prophet Muhammad(S.A.W) reply and says it go to   make sujud for ALLAH`" i would like to know since i have no education in islam is this story true? i use the word swahabas to implies more than one swahaba

Comment: Wa Alaikum As Salam Wr.Wb. There's an authentic hadith from Bukhari that the Sun prostrates itself under the Throne of Allah (ﷻ). Read it here: https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/10 - These are matters of the Unseen.

Comment: You should know about metaphor, Prophet Muhammad sometimes speak in a metaphor/hyperbolic style

Comment: @Rafid ooh that explains a lot thanks for educate me